# jbox2d tutorial

Tags: java, box2d, jbox2d

can you tell me:
where can I find tutorials **"programming games in jbox2d"**?

Answer (score 6):

I have ported the Hello World sample from the C++ manual to jbox2d.  This is just a line by line port. Obviously you need to write a basic java program and call this code. You will also need to import a number of libraries, I had trouble with the formatting of my imports in StackOverflow so I am excluding them.  Hopefully your IDE will take care of the imports for you.

```
    // Static Body
    Vec2  gravity = new Vec2(0,-10);
    World world = new World(gravity);
    BodyDef groundBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    groundBodyDef.position.set(0, -10);
    Body groundBody = world.createBody(groundBodyDef);
    PolygonShape groundBox = new PolygonShape();
    groundBox.setAsBox(50, 10);
    groundBody.createFixture(groundBox, 0);

    // Dynamic Body
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    bodyDef.position.set(0, 4);
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape dynamicBox = new PolygonShape();
    dynamicBox.setAsBox(1, 1);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = dynamicBox;
    fixtureDef.density = 1;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef);

    // Setup world
    float timeStep = 1.0f/60.0f;
    int velocityIterations = 6;
    int positionIterations = 2;

    // Run loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; ++i) {
        world.step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
        Vec2 position = body.getPosition();
        float angle = body.getAngle();
        System.out.printf("%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f\n", position.x, position.y, angle);
    }
```

Comment: Except this code is broken, world no longer supports "doSleep" in jBox2D.

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns I have rectified that. (Waiting for peer-review).

Answer (score 5):

I have developed one simple application using jBox2D and javaFX 2. You can find tutorial and source code for this application [**here**](http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.com/2011/11/hello-world-jbox2d-with-javafx-20.html).

Also you can watch application sample demo video [**here**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T--Av307HG4)

Answer (score 4):

This is not exactly a direct programming-related question, and thus will probably be closed soon.

Regardless, one does not program games *in* JBox2D, one programs games *with* JBox2D. If you're looking for help in using the jbox2d library, a quick Google search turned up [one tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120119002500/http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/) (for android, but I would expect the general use of the library to be quite general) that looks like it may be helpful - alternatively, try the JBox2D [user manual](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf).

On the other hand, if what you *really* want to know is how to program games in general... well, that's a far larger topic and one that is best solved with a Google search for game tutorials. Just remember that game-making is a general topic, not platform specific, so don't shy away from tutorials not written for Java - try and adapt their example code instead, and you may learn even more!